# {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]} after authenticating to twitter

Tags: php, ssl, twitter

I am new to Twitter programming using PHP. So I concluded to use https://github.com/ssx/oauth-twitter-examples/tree/master/multiple-users this example file. After successfull login I am receiving {"errors":[{"message":"SSL is required","code":92}]} and the documentation on https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/ssl is something I am unable to understand. Can anyone please help me to over com this issue.

I have hosted the porgram at https://twittercleanx.azurewebsites.net/a/multiple-users/authorize.php

Comment: SSL is a security certificate. Learn more about it here: http://www.symantec.com/page.jsp?id=ssl-information-center

Comment: @RakeshSharma I have already enabled Open SSL in PHP.ini file